# Wordpress Gutenberg InnerBlocks Change Core Block Supports Color

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to remove the supports for color in the Wordpress Gutenburg core heading block but only within my inner template. Is this possible without creating a new custom block?

```
const Edit = ( props ) => {
    
  const blockProps = useBlockProps();

  const innerAllowed = [ 'core/paragraph', 'core/heading', 'core/button', 'core/image' ];
  const innerTemplate = [ ['core/heading',
      { 
        level: 3, 
        placeHolder:'Enter a Blog RFI Title',
        supports:{ color:{ link:false,background:false,text:false } } 
      } ], 
    ['core/image',{}], ['core/paragraph',{}], ['core/button',{}] ]
    return (
    <section { ...blockProps }>
      <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ innerAllowed } template={ innerTemplate } templateLock={'insert'}>
      </InnerBlocks>
    </section>
    );
};

export default Edit;
```

Comment: Same issue here, did you find any solution for that?